# Minimal Bookdown added jpg reference not rendering image

Tags: r, bookdown

I and attempting to render a single jpg image using the minimal Bookdown setup.

Everything builds and knits fine in the original minimal bookdown state.  When I add this one line of code just below '# Prerequisites,' the book incurs errors during the build process.

I've researched the error solutions to extent of my brain cells but cannot seem to locate the solution.  The line of code works perfectly fine in R markdown, so it's not a file or directory does not exist issue.

When I knit the book, it produces the image in the proper position.

```
     ![](/Users/brianlee/Dropbox (Personal)/__bookdown_dfc/__derivations/flow_diagram.jpg)
```

```
Error messages are provided in linked image[![enter image description here][1]][1].


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0u4B.jpg
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HTML instead `<img src= "/Users/brianlee/Dropbox (Personal)/__bookdown_dfc/__derivations/flow_diagram.jpg">`